# texture problem (going over the whole body)

Tags: texturing

I followed a tutorial for the sims 3 to the sims 4 accessory conversion [here](http://www.sims4studio.com/thread/10/tutorial-using-sims-studio-accessory?page=1), and everything was fine, until I had to add the texture on sims 4 studio.

The object was converted with the protect paint, rigs and everything, still, when I put the 'diffuse' texture on the sims 4 studio, it seems to overline the object itself and go on the whole body.
I thought this could be thanks to something I didn't do right in blender, so I figure it wouldn't hurt asking here.

I'm attaching via mediafire - the blender files and the diffuse and spec maps in case anyone wants to have a look [here](https://www.mediafire.com/file/p5yczr4oivwte0s/spider_basket.rar).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you problem is the UV, your Main character is using all the UV layout and your spider is using all the UV Layout too, once you export both as a single object your are getting only one UV Layout for both objects, you need to arrange your UV's before you move frome Blender[image]

Hope that helps

Good Luck